# How to override a checked out document?

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, document-library, powerpoint

I want to delete a document from my library but the following shows up:

> The file is currently checked out or locked for editing by another
>   user

How do I override the check out changes so that I can be able to delete the document?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have a **high enough permisson level** you can select the document, go over the ribbon to files and click "Discard Check Out".

[image]

(Picture from my SharePoint 2013 on-prem Environment)

Comment: That means if I do not have high permission level I will not be able to discard check out unless I ask the person to check in..

Comment: correct, or you ask your IT department for a higher permission level

Comment: Hmm, I am a site collection owner and have full control of the specific folder where a file resides, and that file doesn't have a checkout icon on it, but trying to delete it gives me the error "this file is checked out for editing by X user"... curious.

Comment: What if I choose "Check In" to override the checkout instead. Does that keep the other user's changes (unless they used a local drafts folder)?